# spring boot batch multi-thread step database connection is closed error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using spring boot with spring batch. I am implementing one of parallel process "multi-thread step" http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html .

I have two datasources configured, one for reading and other one for writing. Here are datasource classes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef="db1TransactionManager",
basePackages ="com.domain1.data.repositories")
public class DataSource1{

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="db1Datasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.db1Datasource")
    public DataSource db1Datasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="db1EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db1EntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(db1Datasource())
                .packages("com.domain1.data.model")
                .persistenceUnit("db1")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db1TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db1TransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("db1EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db1EntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(db1EntityManagerFactory);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef="db2TransactionManager",
basePackages ="com.domain2.data.repositories")
public class DataSource2{

    @Bean(name="db2Datasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.db2Datasource")
    public DataSource db2Datasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name="db2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db2EntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(db2Datasource())
                .packages("com.domain2.data.model")
                .persistenceUnit("db2")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "db2TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("db2EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db2EntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(db2EntityManagerFactory);
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {
       private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("db1Datasource")
    private DataSource bd1Datasource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("db2EntityManagerFactory")
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db2EntityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("db2TransactionManager")
    private PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager;

    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<table1> table1Reader() throws Exception {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM table1;
        JdbcCursorItemReader<table1> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<table1>();
        reader.setSql(sql);
        reader.setDataSource(db1Datasource);
        reader.setRowMapper(new resultSetMapper());
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        reader.setSaveState(true);
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public dbProcessor dbProcessor() {
        return new dbProcessor ();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<table2> table2Writer() {
        JpaItemWriter<table2> writer = new JpaItemWriter<table2>();
        writer.setEntityManagerFactory(table2EntityManagerFactory.getObject());
        return writer;
    }

     @Bean(name="batchJob")
     public Job batchJobJob() throws Exception {
           return jobBuilderFactory.get("batchJobJob")
                      .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                      .listener(new JobCompletionNotificationListener())
                      .flow(batchStep())
                      .end()
                      .build();
     }

     @Bean
     public Step batchStep() throws Exception {
         return stepBuilderFactory.get("batchStep")
                 .transactionManager(batchTransactionManager)
                 .<table1, table2> chunk(100)
                 .reader(table1Reader())
                 .processor(Processor())
                 .writer(table2Writer())
                 .faultTolerant()
                 .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                 .build();
     }

     @Bean
     public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){


SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor=new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("batch_task");
                 asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(5);
         return asyncTaskExecutor;
     }

}
```

I am `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:` The connection is closed error.

If i do not use taskExecutor bean it works fines. In this case what i am missing? Can you help me what needs to done? Also Which approach is good in parallel processing? Multithread-step or partitioning?

Thanks

Comment: It is very hard to read your code due to formatting. Can you please update your question with correctly formatted code? The more readable you make your question, the more likely it is you will receive an answer. Welcome to SO!

Comment: I have formatted the code. please check now.